Combining two tables with multiple IDs in each table
I'm trying to combine tables, each which has a person ID (multiple in each table). I would like to combine the two data sets, so that, for each person_ID with a unique date of surgery, they get assigned all their potential infection dates (made up in table 2).
I have tried various joins in PySpark - but that has not gone very well and tends to exclude too many variables.
I was not sure if there is a function or if I need to write a loop to run through all the variables (>40k rows in each table)


can you provide a small reproducible example with code?
